# Line Integrals of Vector Fields, Homework Conundrum

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

I am a student and I have a conflict with a given answer in the textbook. The question is the following:

Evaluate the line integral $\int_C \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r}$ for the given vector field $\mathbf{F}$ and the specified curve $C$.

$\mathbf{F} = \mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{r}$, where $\mathbf{a}$ is a constant vector, $\mathbf{r} = \langle x, y, z \rangle$, and $C$ is a straight line segment from $\mathbf{r}_1$ to $\mathbf{r}_2$.

Here is my solution:

$$\int_C \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r} = \int_C (\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{r}) \cdot d\mathbf{r} = 0$$
because the triple product of coplanar vectors vanishes.

However, the solution given is $\mathbf{r}_2 \cdot (\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{r}_1)$.

Comment: I don't see a triple product of coplanar vectors. How about writing $r=r_1+t(r_2-r_1)$ and actually doing the integration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the comment by Lord Shark the Unknown, I let
\begin{align}
\mathbf{r} & = \mathbf{r}_1 + t(\mathbf{r}_2 - \mathbf{r}_1) \\
\Longrightarrow \quad d\mathbf{r} & = (\mathbf{r}_2 - \mathbf{r}_1)\,dt.
\end{align}

We now have
\begin{align}
\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{r} & = \mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{r}_1 + t(\mathbf{r}_2 - \mathbf{r}_1) \\
& = \mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{r}_1 + t\mathbf{a} \times (\mathbf{r}_2 - \mathbf{r}_1).
\end{align}

And finally
\begin{align}
\int_C \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r} & = \int_0^1 (\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{r}_1 + t\mathbf{a} \times (\mathbf{r}_2 - \mathbf{r}_1)) \cdot (\mathbf{r}_2 - \mathbf{r}_1)\,dt \\
& = \int_0^1 (\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{r}_1) \cdot (\mathbf{r}_2 - \mathbf{r}_1)\,dt \\
& = \int_0^1 (\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{r}_1) \cdot \mathbf{r}_2\,dt = (\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{r}_1) \cdot \mathbf{r}_2.
\end{align}